# EclipseLink: Is weaving applied only to super parent class?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Lets suppose we have tree classes:

```
@Entity 
class ClassA extends ClassB{
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
class ClassB extends ClassC{
...
}


@MappedSuperclass
class ClassC{
...
}
```

I have serious suspicious that in such case we need to weave only ClassC. I tried static weaving only to ClassC and everything works. In particular EntityGraph for ClassA (FetchGroup) which needs weaving works.